# How to write a better function for validating date in ruby in yyyy-mm-dd format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I have tried many ways of writing a validate date function in ruby which handles all the edge cases like , if the current date is valid according to leap year, and also if the date is passed in invalid format like 20-05-2022 it should return false , it should only valid format of date in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Functions I tried before asking here(this function I got from one of the Stackoverflow link):

```
require 'date'

def validate_date?(string)
  date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
  DateTime.strptime(date, date_format)
  true
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end
```

But the problem with this function is it is not able to handle some of the invalid date formats like :

```
validate_date('202200-06-02')  -> returns true (As the date is in incorrect format)
validate_date('2022-060-002')  -> returns true (As the date is in incorrect format)
```

I want to return false if these invalid date formats are applied.

Any suggestions or improvements are welcome, or even what else should I try to write a proper validate_date function which can be used for all kinds of edge cases.

Comment: i think `202200` is actually a valid year.

Comment: I would also argue that `2022-060-002` is kind of okay because the format is a bit weird but it is still unambiguous and parses correctly. Instead of just validating the data string I suggest validating and sanitizing it. Because you can parse the date string you can also write it back into your preferred format.

Comment: @spickerman Actually I am taking the date from query params for an API so if the user enters let's say 20220 we should not allow right ?  Because this is not the valid format. Also taking the data string and then formatting it will be a good idea ?

Comment: As Lam Phan already wrote 20220 is actually a valid year - just far in the future. Where do you want to draw the line? Are only dates until today allowed? Or up to the next year? The next one hundred years?

Comment: I suggest you start by fixing your example. The method is `validate_date?` but you're calling `validate_date` (without `?`). Also the method's argument is `string` but you're using `date` which gives a `NameError`. Once you fix these, your 2nd call does return `false`.

Comment: Dates are only allowed I think in yyyy-mm-dd format which I already mentioned.

Comment: @stefan No I am calling it using validate_date?('20220-060-01') but it does not work as it is .

Comment: @NavinOjha `DateTime.strptime('20220-060-01', '%Y-%m-%d')` raises an error saying "invalid date" on my system which seems correct. If you get a different result, what Ruby version are you running?

Comment: Looks like ISO8601. It's [built in](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-iso8601).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Rails you can use method `to_date` in combination with regexp

```rb
def valid_date?(string)
  !!(string.to_date && /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/ =~ string)
rescue Date::Error
  false
end
```

If you are not

```rb
require 'date'

def valid_date?(string)
  !!(Date.parse(string) && /^\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/ =~ string)
rescue Date::Error
  false
end
```

Comment: In Ruby, you usually want `\A` and `\z` instead of `^` and `$`.

Comment: `\A` and `\z` aren't the convention in Ruby for begin and start string. There is a difference between `\A` `\z` and `^` `$`. `^` - Matches beginning of line, `$` - matches end of line, `\A` - Matches beginning of string, `\z` - Matches end of string. But I agree that in this case more suitable is `\A` and `\z`